# Printing varbinary data in Python retrieve from mysql-connector query

Tags: python, dataframe, mysql-connector, varbinary

Thanks for all the knowledged shared within Stackoverflow.

I have an issue printing varbinary data retrieved from a MySQL database using Python3 and the mysql_connector library.  The varbinary column (RawTxt) is stored as varbinary in MySQL and shows up like a list of numbers within brackets [] when retrieved in Python.

Would I cast it first then print? I tried adding " charset='utf8' " parameter to the connection variable to no avail.  Not sure if it is even a charset / codec problem.  This seems a little specialized for I can't find much on the internet about it.

Below is the code, a print using df.head(), and then what it looks like when sent to a .csv file with df.to_csv

Code:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
import pandas as pd

dbconn = mysql.connect(
    host = '1234.com',
    user = 'root',
    password = '1234',
    database = 'tq_verbatims'
)

dbcursor = dbconn.cursor()
dbcursor.execute("""
SELECT a.RawID, b.RawTxt, c.GibberishOdds, a.cntResp 
FROM tq_verbatims.tblRawSpellingsCoded a, tq_verbatims.tblRawSpellings b, tq_verbatims.tblGibberishOdds c 
WHERE a.RawID = b.RawID AND b.SanitizedRawID = c.SanitizedRawID;
"""
)

tblRawSpellingCoded = dbcursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(tblRawSpellingCoded, columns=dbcursor.column_names)
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\export_dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)
df.head()
```

df.head() result:

```
  RawID   RawTxt      GibberishOdds   cntResp
0   116 [40, 85, 78, 75, 78, 79, 87, 78, 41]    0.050513    1
1   237 [46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46]    2.718280    1
2   284 [46, 78, 79, 84, 32, 83, 85, 82, 69]    0.079919    1
3   585 [51, 32, 77]    2.718280    6
4   658 [51, 77]    2.718280    403
```

Within the .csv file, the RawTxt field shows as *bytearray(b'(UNKOWN)')* in the .csv file output where it should have just had the text 'UNKNOWN'.  The RawTxt actual data for those 4 rows is *'UNKNOWN', '......', 'NOT SURE', '3 M'*

```
RawID, RawTxt, GibberishOdds, cntResp
116,bytearray(b'(UNKNOWN)'),0.0505134,1
237,bytearray(b'......'),2.71828,1
284,bytearray(b'.NOT SURE'),0.0799194,1
585,bytearray(b'3 M'),2.71828,6
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the `RawTxt` field is being exported as `bytearray` is because the `cursor` is returning the values in that field as `bytearray` values. Without knowing the exact schema of your tables, it's difficult to tell why `RawTxt` is converted to `bytearray` by the `mysql-connector` package.

In any case, if you are certain that `RawTxt` contains valid string values, then you can convert the values to a string before or after you've passed the data to `Pandas`.

###### Before `Pandas`:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
import pandas as pd

dbconn = mysql.connect(
    host = '1234.com',
    user = 'root',
    password = '1234',
    database = 'tq_verbatims'
)

dbcursor = dbconn.cursor()
dbcursor.execute("""
SELECT a.RawID, b.RawTxt, c.GibberishOdds, a.cntResp 
FROM tq_verbatims.tblRawSpellingsCoded a, tq_verbatims.tblRawSpellings b, tq_verbatims.tblGibberishOdds c 
WHERE a.RawID = b.RawID AND b.SanitizedRawID = c.SanitizedRawID;
"""
)
tblRawSpellingCoded = []
for row in dbcursor.fetchall():
    row[1] = row[1].decode('utf8')
    tblRawSpellingCoded.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(tblRawSpellingCoded, columns=dbcursor.column_names)
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\export_dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)
df.head()
```

###### After `Pandas`:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
import pandas as pd

dbconn = mysql.connect(
    host = '1234.com',
    user = 'root',
    password = '1234',
    database = 'tq_verbatims'
)

dbcursor = dbconn.cursor()
dbcursor.execute("""
SELECT a.RawID, b.RawTxt, c.GibberishOdds, a.cntResp 
FROM tq_verbatims.tblRawSpellingsCoded a, tq_verbatims.tblRawSpellings b, tq_verbatims.tblGibberishOdds c 
WHERE a.RawID = b.RawID AND b.SanitizedRawID = c.SanitizedRawID;
"""
)

tblRawSpellingCoded = dbcursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(tblRawSpellingCoded, columns=dbcursor.column_names)
df.RawTxt = df.RawTxt.str.decode('utf8')
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\export_dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)
df.head()
```

Either of the solutions should convert the `RawTxt` values from `bytearray` values to `string`, with the assumption that the values are valid string values.

Comment: The column is stored as varbinary in the MySQL table so it's output was that type.  Basically, you are saying, "just change the type when you import it."    I can definately use that. Thanks, Abdou.